# Shuffling different values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that I should train, but before I have to re-organize data.

I should shuffle RANDOM columns values as shown below (Matching values of player 1 and 2)

**Starting point**

```
|-----------|-----------|---------------|--------------|---------------|--------------|
|   Winner  |   Loser   | Winner Weight | Loser Weight | Winner Height | Loser Height |
|-----------|-----------|---------------|--------------|---------------|--------------|
|     Tom   |    Jack   |      88       |      77      |      178      |     189      |
|     Ash   |    Zuck   |      90       |      69      |      190      |     177      |
|     Ben   |    Mark   |      86       |      88      |      198      |     179      |
|-----------|-----------|---------------|--------------|---------------|--------------|
```

**Ending point**

```
|-----------|-----------|---------------|--------------|--------------|-------------|---------|
| Player 1  |  Player 2 |   P1 Weight   |   P2 Weight  |   P1 Height  |   P2 Height |  Winner |
|-----------|-----------|---------------|--------------|--------------|-------------|---------|
|    Jack   |    Tom    |      77       |      88      |      189     |     177     |    1    |
|     Ash   |    Zuck   |      90       |      69      |      190     |     177     |    0    |
|    Mark   |    Ben    |      88       |      86      |      179     |     198     |    1    |
|-----------|-----------|---------------|--------------|--------------|-------------|---------|
```

Comment: And the logic of this transformations is?

Comment: @ipj  should shuffle random, but the values have to agree with the player 1 / 2

Comment: So is it possible to shuffle combination for example `Jack` and `Zuck` in the same row?

Comment: Nope, each row is a tennis match, and I cannot mix different rows @ipj

Comment: Ok, but is (Tom,Jack) the same as (Jack,Tom) or is it just required shuffling as You say? Can the order of rows remain the same, and only order of pairs should be changed?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to convert to records, apply logic to each, and convert back to df:

```
def convert_d(d):    
    new_d = {}
    p1 = random.choice(['Winner', 'Loser'])
    p2 = [x for x in ['Winner', 'Loser'] if x!=p1][0]
    new_d['Player 1'] = d[p1]
    new_d['Player 2'] = d[p2]
    new_d['P1 Weight'] = d[f'{p1} Weight']
    new_d['P2 Weight'] = d[f'{p2} Weight']
    new_d['P1 Height'] = d[f'{p1} Height']
    new_d['P2 Height'] = d[f'{p2} Height']
    if p1=='Winner':
        new_d['Winner'] = 0
    else:
        new_d['Winner'] = 1
    return new_d

pd.DataFrame.from_records([convert_d(d) for d in df.to_dict(orient='records')])


    Player 1    Player 2    P1 Weight   P2 Weight   P1 Height   P2 Height   Winner
0   Tom         Jack        88            77           178      189         0
1   Ash         Zuck        90            69           190      177         0
2   Ben         Mark        86            88           198      179         0
```